# How to use a CSS sprite for a Repeating background image?

Tags: html, css

This is something that I have had trouble with in the past and it's on my mind so I made a simple example sprite image to test and hopefully get some answers  with.

If you view my code and demo here
http://dabblet.com/gist/2263037

You will see that I have a simple div that uses a background image

Below that DIV I have the same div but this time I attempt to use a CSS Sprite image instead

So my question, is it possible to replicate the look of the first DIV using this sprite image or are changes needed on the sprite image?

Without Sprite image

```
/* Notice wrapper with Single Image */
.notice-wrap {
    margin-top: 10px; padding: 0 .7em;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
    background: #B81900 url(http://www.getklok.com/css/ui-lightness/images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_18_b81900_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat;
}
```

With Sprite image

```
/* Notice wrapper with SPRITE Image */
.notice-wrap-sprite {
    margin-top: 10px; padding: 0 .7em;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
    background: #fff url(http://f.cl.ly/items/2P1u2S1a132R0B3d2s08/test-sprite.png) repeat;
    background-position: 0 -52px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="notice-wrap"> 
       <p><strong>NOTICE:</strong> This is just a test notice, no reason to be alarmed</p> 
</div>

<BR><BR><BR>

<div class="notice-wrap-sprite"> 
       <p><strong>NOTICE:</strong> This is just a test notice, no reason to be alarmed</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Setting up the sprite

You can use an image sprite to do what you want.  They can only repeat along one axis, i.e. repeat-x, but in your case that's all you need. Also your image within the sprite must run the entire width, this is how the browser knows to tile it.

The trick is your repeated background must extend across the **FULL WIDTH** of your sprite image.  This is crucial.  Here is your image, modified to meet that criterion:

[image]

## Setting up the CSS

Now we just reference it as usual, and it will work fine:

```
/* Notice wrapper with SPRITE Image */
.notice-wrap-sprite {
    margin-top: 10px; padding: 0 .7em;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
    background: #fff url(http://f.cl.ly/items/2P1u2S1a132R0B3d2s08/test-sprite3.png) repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 -52px;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get it working?  This should be do-able.  If not, let me know where you're stuck.

Comment: I have an updated demo with all my attempts and 3 different images here http://dabblet.com/gist/2263840 I don't think it's possible

Comment: It's possible, I've uploaded a new sprite file for you and the associated code.  It should work as you're expecting.

Comment: @jasondavis, as msigman said, it is possible, you just need to adjust your image as msigman has done in his answer. Try using his image in your dabblet. It should work. That is unless I misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have to put the sprite on it's own row in this case. This should work since your image is constrained vertically to a set height. At least that's what it looks like in the example.

Additionally the image would need to be the same width as the sprite. The reason the background image needs to extend the width of the sprite is because you are repeating across the x-axis and if there is blank space or another image to the left of your sprite, you will get something similar to your example.

In your example, the images in your sprite may not be a good fit with that background image since they are so wide. So it would be better if you selected other images that fit the size of that background image, probably more background images since usually you can use thinner images. See example below that I use on one of my websites.

And as msigman said, you can add repeat-x to make sure the background only repeats along the x-axis, but if you've constrained your div to a certain height and positioned the sprite correctly, the repeat-x may not matter, but it is safer.

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean now, I have made another demo here http://dabblet.com/gist/2263840 which has my previous 2 examples plus a new emaple using a new sprite and the repeat-x and you can see how the div is too wide

Comment: I'ts a shame you can't do what I was trying to do

Comment: Yeah, sprites are a pain to work with, you have to position images so carefully.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Sprite is neither a method nor an attribute in CSS. CSS Sprite is a simple trick to load multiple images with a single http request. This is the cause CSS Sprite helps to improve performance of a web application by reducing the loading time for several images. To implement CSS Sprite we need CSS attributes like Width, Height, Background, Position Left & Right.

Look at the example below. Here I have a single png file (demoImg.png) with 4 sub images. Sub images are cloud, clock, message & love symbols. Using CSS Sprite I am showing all these 4 sub images to each individual HTML image tags. To identify image tags I used id’s (#cloud, #clock, #message & #love) for each img tag. By setting image src=”trans.gif” I am loading an transparent image similar to the width & height of sub image. To show each image individually with respective image tag I am applying CSS attributes background, width & height to the image using id selector.

Look at the example [CSS Sprite images Example](https://jharaphula.com/css-sprite-images-example/)