# How to sprite body background in CSS

Tags: css

I'm working on small php script.

I have  problem with css sprites.
I have image with 96px the left side is 48px the right side is 48px.
I want to use the left side of image as body background.
And i want to use the right side of the image as backgroud of div.
The problem is i don't know how to use the left side as background.

Help please.

Comment: Can you show your codes ( HTML & CSS ) ?

Comment: body{background:url(img/ap.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat #181818;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Sprites only work when you can limit the size of the element to the size of the *section* of the image you want to display.

Use separate images.

Comment: I'm not agree with this.. you can set an sprite image for background repeat with no problem, the trick is how you made the `sprite image` and of course, set up the `css` file. For example and with a `width="96px"` where each image is the half (48px wide), you could do a `repeat-y` and have a repeated background image from a sprite one.

Comment: @gmo I believe that's what Quentin meant.  I think he intended that you can't have a sprite with a bunch of icons on it **and** use it for _repeating_ backgrounds.

Comment: @gmo I didnt not understant im not talking about repeat im talkin about how to set the righ side as background

Comment: Well, could be.. but the comment `only work` it's what I'm not agree with. If you have a bunch of icons, you still can have a repeated one, if (and only if) one of those cover the full width (or height) then you can.

Comment: @checkopenport, can you post and example... maybe I'm not understand you exactly of what you are after.

Comment: http://www.checkopenport.com/nasser/img/ap.jpg this is the image ! the problem is that i want to use the left side as repeated background of my body ! And i want to use the right side as a background of a div !

Comment: @checkopenport you can use it as a repeated background BUT ONLY vertically for that image.. not to cover the full body & div, look these example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955967/how-to-use-a-css-sprite-for-a-repeating-background-image

Comment: You can use sprites for repeating backgrounds, but **only** if the width of the image *in* the sprite is the same width as the element (or height if you are repeating horizontally). Otherwise you can't stop the next image along in the sprite showing up as well. Since the body needs to be wider then the (aprox) 20px wide image in the sprite, you can't use a sprite here.