# css background pattern sprites revisited

Tags: html, css, sprite

Using css sprites for icon-style images is best practice by now and pretty easy.

Using multiple repeating backgrounds in one image is traditionally only possible if they either use only vertical or horizontal repeat.

Or is it? Meanwhile with css3 and html5 and all stuff, is there a way to combine multiple background images in one css sprite to make an background pattern and use vertical and horizontal repetition?

Edit/Note: I know this is not the first time such a question is asked. But most/all answers I found are some time ago. I'm just wondering if there is a solution today.

Edit: To illustrate what I'm looking for: http://ibin.co/21LqyJvnGdMB

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Hi. What code? This is a general "Is it possible to ..." question. I'd expect answers like "No, you still have to use multiple images" or "yes, look here, this is how it's done." I apologise if I haven't managed to make this more clear but I honestly don't know how?

Comment: This is 4 years ago. Perhaps there is a solution today?

Comment: @Scheintod - To represent a visual scenario of the thing that you have mentioned above would be very much appreciated rather than just taking it as a generic view of whether it is possible now or not. You need to illustrate to attract better chances of getting it answered as well as making it helpful for others who can view this post 10-15 years from now also :)

Comment: Sorry but what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I don't think there has been anything added to css 3 that allows for the same thing as the `moz-image-rect`, but I did come across a few posts that say you can use some background positioning but it would also mean the your repeating image would need to take up the [whole of one side of your sprite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955967/how-to-use-a-css-sprite-for-a-repeating-background-image).  but again, most posts about this topic are around 3 to 4 years old so I guess there hasn't been much movement on this on the css 3 front

Comment: I've added an image to show what exactly I'm asking for. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: @Duplicate: Are there any policies on SO that prevent/forbid asking if there has come something new up on a subject already asked years ago?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use css sprites for repeating background.

> The rule is pretty simple: if you want the background to repeat
>   vertically (top to bottom), place the images in the sprite
>   horizontally (left to right) and make sure the individual images in
>   the sprite have the same height. For the opposite case: when you want
>   to repeat horizontally, sprite vertically.

check this article for better understanding. http://www.phpied.com/background-repeat-and-css-sprites/

Comment: I think he wanted "...and use vertical and horizontal repetition?"