# select part of an image and repeat it as a background

Tags: css, background-position

i want to select 5px of this image (Sprites) and repeat it as a background

19px left side - 5px in the middle - 19px right side

```
Div:first-child{background:url(frame.png) left center no-repeat;} 
Div:last-child{background:url(frame.png) right center no-repeat;} 
Div{background:url(frame.png) center center repeat-y;}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to do, why is it not working? Please paste your code with the not working solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a CSS sprite for a Repeating background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955967/how-to-use-a-css-sprite-for-a-repeating-background-image)

Comment: @Florian I just edited it

Comment: So change "center, right, left" values to -10px or -20% or 90%... etc...

Comment: @KYSSE it doesn't work like that i need a specific width