# When I try to repeat x an image sprite, it shows the entire image instead

Tags: html, css, background, repeat

I am trying to repeat this part ([pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm8vv.png) which is the arrow bit) from this image ([pic 2](https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif)). However, it doesn't take that port of the image to repeat. It just shows the the entire image. How can I fix this (and still keep using image sprites).

The image sprite's width is `134px` and the height is `44px`

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.test-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #000;
    background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif") -84px -18px repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-box">this is a text message</div>
```

If I were to use a normal image (not an image sprite) then it works. But I want to use a image sprite. Eg of it working when its not an image sprite

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.test-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #000;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm8vv.png") repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-box">this is a text message</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a CSS sprite for a Repeating background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955967/how-to-use-a-css-sprite-for-a-repeating-background-image)

Comment: @cjl750 doesn't work. Already saw this post before I made this question

Comment: The point of the answer in that question is that doing what you want to do purely with CSS is impossible; you must set up your image sprite in a specific way to make this possible. The image you're using in this example won't work because it isn't set up to allow repeating.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you image is too big. Open it and check https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif

You can set attribute `background-size` with normal `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` and you image will repeat

Comment: Can you show me the example in code form? I edited my post and put in the size of the image sprite in pixels. `Width = 134px` and `height = 44px`